# Error when inserting into a Temp Table in stored Proc, but works fine in separate Query window

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, type-conversion

I run the following code in query Analyzer, and works fine no issue, but when I run the same code in a stored proc I get the following conversion error. I have the exact same code in the stored proc but always error. In the table I am looking at 99% of the vales are numbers, but there are a few text values in there, which is needed for the system running it. I can't figure out why it will not run in the stored proc. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 21.
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SUPERSTOCK' to data type int.

See Below for Code --

```sql
 DECLARE @v NVARCHAR(MAX)
                 SET @v = 'SELECT CostCentre, bload, dbo.getdateonly(Orderdate) FROM burjobsql.dbo.Orders WHERE Job = ' + CHAR(39) +  '119720' + CHAR(39) + ' AND CostCentre IN (' + CHAR(39) + '300' + CHAR(39) + ')'

                                                              
    DECLARE @VariedOrder Table

        (

        Costcode VARCHAR(10),
        Bload INT,
        OrderDate VARCHAR(15) 

        )
        INSERT @VariedOrder 
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @v
        SELECT * FROM @VariedOrder
```

Comment: The error comes from the Costcode column BTW.

Comment: Perhaps only a typo but in @v you refer to CostCentre, but the column in the table is named Costcode.

Comment: Why are you running the statement using `sys_sp_executesql` here? There's no need to.

Comment: What is the data type for `bload` from table `Orders` ?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is completely unnecessary here. Is there any reason why the table variable does not have the same data types? And what does `dbo.getdateonly` do and why does it output `varchar`?

Comment: Thanx Guys, i figure it out, i just had to use Char(39) in my dynamic query